# Function store_result() for slow mysql connection

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem with the OVH MySQL. Continue to lost connection. I have think to use store_result() but I don't know how to add in this function

**CODE:**

```
function executeQuery($query) {
    $db = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
    if ($db == FALSE)
        return -1;
    if ((mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $db)) == FALSE)
        return -1;
    $result = mysql_query($query, $db);

    if ($result == FALSE)
        return -2;
    if (!($result === true)) {
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            $ret[] = $row;
        }
    } else {
        $ret[] = $result;
    }
    mysql_close($db);
    if (isset($ret))
        return $ret;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use **PDO** or **MySQLi**, because **mysql_*** functions are depreciated.

Comment: To which `store_result()` function do you relate to with your question? And what is the rationale to use it when you experience lost connections?

Comment: Your conditionals are confusing. Why are you type checking for ! true, but assuming false for your first $result check. If mysql_query returns false you'll never make it to that conditional in the first place, so that's one place to check.

Comment: `if ($result == FALSE)` and `if (!($result === true)) {` are same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are actually doing something very wrong.

Each time you call the `executeQuery()` function, a new `mysql_connect()` is established and then followed by a `mysql_select_db()`. This is pretty expensive and not the right way. You need to reuse the already established connection here.

There is already an answer available [`here`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13284898/1003917) on how to reuse connections.

Secondly, you are using an obselete database API i.e. the **`mysql_*`** functions which is deprecated. Switch to **`MySQLi`** or **`PDO`**.